# Spark_SQL where will the schema and the table data be stored?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Spark(Spark_SQL), I have loaded data into spark_sql I've also created the table and loaded some data into it.
My question is: where will the schema and the table data be stored?

Answer (score 3):

> where table schema is stored

The Hive metastore

Default is a Derby Database as the "metastore". You can open the folder you ran the Spark job, you'll notice a `metastore_db` folder

When using Hive, then the Hive metastore is a MySQL, Postgres, Oracle database that was establish when Hive was installed.

> where table will be stored

The Hive warehouse directory

HDFS `/apps/hive/warehouse/<databasename>/<tablename>.db/`, for example on a Hortonworks environment.

The default SparkSQL will save a Gzipped Parquet file into that directory as a sequentially numbered `part-00xyz` file meaning "partition".